# Encontrar un caracter que no sea un espacio ni una letra, incluyendo tildes y diacríticos del español

Tags: java, android, regex

Deseo incluir el ***espacio*** y que sólo acepte ***letras, números y tildes*** y el carácter especial ***ñ***. Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente:

```
if (primernombre.length() == 0 || a.matches(".*[^a-zñáéíóúA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ].*")) {
        primernombre.setError("Ingrese un nombre valido. Solo letras.");
```

lo que me falta es incluir el espacio y los números.

Por ejemplo:  **esto es un texto** hasta ahora no lo acepta , y mi expresión regular acepta solamente **estoesuntexto**

Comment: Yo uso la propiedad:                          android:digits="QWEÉRTYUÚÜIÍOÓPAÁSDFGHJKLÑZXCVBNM qweértyuúüiíoópaásdfghjklñzxcvbnm&#39;&amp;-.#1234567890"
 en mi EditText... Y el carácter espacio es solo un espacio.

Comment: esta expresión te funciona con el espacio ?

Comment: sí, es la que uso. Pero no la agregue como repuesta, porque no estas pidiendo el código xml

Comment: @Felix tené en cuenta que no estás considerando `[üÜ]`.

Comment: @Mariano gracias por la acotación

Comment: @Mariano gracias por el apunte!, he modificado mi respuesta para que contemple el caso que dices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Has probado a añadir el espacio en tu conjunto de carácteres?

Te quedaría algo así tu expresión

```
a.matches("^[a-zñáéíóúüA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9 ]$")
```

**Editado**

Puedes probar también esta expresión:

```
^\w+( \w+)*$
```

Esta expresión permitirá una serie de al menos una palabra y las palabras se dividirán por espacios.

`^` Marca el principio del string

`\w+` Indica una serie de al menos una palabra de un carácter o número

`( \w+)*` indica un grupo que se repite 0 o más veces. En el grupo se espera un espacio seguido por una serie de al menos un carácter o número.

`$` indica el final del string

Esto también se puede traducir por la siguiente expresión:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9ñáéíóúüÜÑÁÉÍÓÚ]+( [a-zA-Z0-9ñáéíóúüÜÑÁÉÍÓÚ]+)*$
```

Comment: La verdad a funcionado el espacio, ahora acepta números, letras, tildes, la ñ y el espacio ha quedado de esta manera  *a.matches(".*[^a-zñáéíóú0-9 A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ0-9 ].*"))*

Comment: He ampliado un poco la respuesta por si lo que te interesa es que la cadena esté separada por espacios y forzar que empiece por un carácter

Comment: Gracias por el trabajo, me ha ayudado bastante !

Comment: De nada, espero te haya servido!!